# javascript for loop with API request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm used to PHP, doing first thing in js/nodejs. I guess this is some sync/async problem. I have array of currencies and trying to do a for loop with API call. In output you can see three different json outputs (different order everytime) but when I am trying to save the value in the file, I get only the last one from array. Also the `var c` has same value in console logs (TESTBTC)
array:

```
TESTUSDT,TESTUSD,TESTBTC,
```

code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

var currencies = (fs.readFileSync('funding_currencies.txt', 'utf-8'));
const currencies_array = currencies.split(",");

for (i = 0; i < currencies_array.length - 1; i++) {
  var c = currencies_array[i];

  if (fs.existsSync('frr_' + c + '.txt')) {
    var oldfrr = (fs.readFileSync('frr_' + c + '.txt', 'utf-8'));
    fs.writeFile("frr_" + c + "_old.txt", oldfrr, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  console.log("funding/stats/" + c + "/hist");

  var baseUrl = "https://api-pub.bitfinex.com/v2/";
  var pathParams = "funding/stats/f" + c + "/hist";
  var queryParams = "limit=1";

  axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${pathParams}?${queryParams}`)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    var raw = JSON.stringify(response.data);
    var partsArray = raw.split(',');
    var frr = 100 * 365 * partsArray[3];
    console.log(c + ' - Daily Rate % FRR: ' + frr);

    fs.writeFile("frr_" + c + ".txt", frr, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("FRR for " + c + " saved to file");
    });
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

}
```

output:

```
funding/stats/TESTUSDT/hist
funding/stats/TESTUSD/hist
funding/stats/TESTBTC/hist
[
  [
    1675598700000,   null,
    null,            0.00000128,
    39.56,           null,
    null,            748236.20624443,
    676828.07200483, null,
    null,            10865216.1584813
  ]
]
TESTBTC - Daily Rate % FRR: 0.04672
[
  [
    1675598700000,   null,
    null,            0.00002035,
    69.88,           null,
    null,            519081.88192342,
    519081.08203316, null,
    null,            0
  ]
]
TESTBTC - Daily Rate % FRR: 0.742775
[
  [
    1675598700000,    null,
    null,             0.00000386,
    28.31,            null,
    null,             6372417.33205204,
    6372417.33205204, null,
    null,             0
  ]
]
TESTBTC - Daily Rate % FRR: 0.14089000000000002
FRR for TESTBTC saved to file
FRR for TESTBTC saved to file
FRR for TESTBTC saved to file
```

So I need to save the values in right associations in right files

Comment: It’d probably be worth taking a step back and running through since general JS async programming tutorials real quick. It’d be easier to see what’s breaking if functionality was split up into smaller chunks.

Comment: Tangential, but the NideJS API docs are you friend, eg https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscopyfilesyncsrc-dest-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only *one* variable `c`, which is accessed by *all* the asynchronous `response => {...}` functions spawned by the `axios.get` statements. Because of their asynchronousness, all these functions will see the last value that `c` takes.

To get one variable *per execution*, replace the `for` loop with the following:

```
currencies_array.forEach(function(c) {
  if (fs.existsSync('frr_' + c + '.txt')) {
  ...
}
```